# Array and __rmul__ operator in Python Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In a project, I created a class, and I needed an operation between this new class and a real matrix, so I overloaded the `__rmul__` function like this

```
class foo(object):

    aarg = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.aarg = 1


    def __rmul__(self,A):
        print(A)
        return 0

    def __mul__(self,A):
        print(A)
        return 0
```

but when I called it, the result wasn't what I expected

```
A = [[i*j for i in np.arange(2)  ] for j in np.arange(3)]
A = np.array(A)
R = foo()
C =  A * R
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
1
0
2
```

It seems that the function is called 6 times, once for each elements.

Instead, the `__mul__` function works greatly

```
C = R * A
```

Output:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]]
```

If `A` isn't an array, but only a list of lists, both work fine

```
A = [[i*j for i in np.arange(2)  ] for j in np.arange(3)]
R = foo()
C =  A * R
C = R * A
```

Output

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

I'd really want for my `__rmul__` function to work also on arrays (my original multiplication function isn't commutative). How can I solve it?

Comment: How do you feel about checking the type of `A`?

Answer (score 7):

**The behaviour is expected.**

First of all you have to understand how an operation like `x*y` is actually executed. The python interpreter will **first** try to compute `x.__mul__(y)`.
If this call returns `NotImplemented` it will **then** try to compute `y.__rmul__(x)`.
**Except** when `y` is a proper subclass of the type of `x`, in this case the interpreter will first consider `y.__rmul__(x)` and then `x.__mul__(y)`.

Now what happens is that `numpy` treats arguments differently depending on whether or not he thinks the argument are scalar or arrays.

When dealing with arrays `*` does element-by-element multiplication, while scalar multiplication multiplies all the entry of an array by the given scalar.

In your case `foo()` is considered as a scalar by numpy, and thus numpy multiplies all elements of the array by `foo`. Moreover, since numpy doesn't know about the type `foo` it returns an array with `dtype=object`, so the object returned is:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Note: `numpy`'s array does *not* return `NotImplemented` when you try to compute the product, so the interpreter calls numpy's array `__mul__` method, which performs scalar multiplication as we said. At this point numpy will try to multiply each entry of the array by your "scalar" `foo()`, and here's is where your `__rmul__` method gets called, because the numbers in the array return `NotImplemented` when their `__mul__` is called with a `foo` argument.

Obviously if you change the order of the arguments to the initial multiplication your `__mul__` method gets called immediately and you don't have any trouble.

So, to answer your question, one way to handle this is to have `foo` inherit from `ndarray`, so that the second rule applies:

```
class foo(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls):
       # you must implement __new__
    # code as before
```

Warning however that [subclassing `ndarray` isn't straightforward](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.subclassing.html).
Moreover you might have other side effects, since now your class is an `ndarray`.

Comment: By what logic does numpy decide that `foo` instances are scalar?

Comment: @wim If it is not an array it's a scalar. As simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

You can define `__numpy_ufunc__` function in your class. It works even **without subclassing** the `np.ndarray`. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#output-type-determination).

Here is an example based on your case:

```
class foo(object):

    aarg = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.aarg = 1

    def __numpy_ufunc__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __rmul__(self,A):
        print(A)
        return 0

    def __mul__(self,A):
        print(A)
        return 0
```

And if we try it,

```
A = [[i*j for i in np.arange(2)  ] for j in np.arange(3)]
A = np.array(A)
R = foo()
C =  A * R
```

Output:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]]
```

It works!

Comment: `__numpy_ufunc__` is now called `__array_ufunc__`, and has slightly different behaviour, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/neps/ufunc-overrides.html

Answer (score 3):

I could not explain the underlying problem as precise as Bakuriu, but there might be another solution.

You can force numpy to use your evaluation method by defining `__array_priority__`. As explained [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) in the numpy docs.

In your case you had to change your class definition to:

```
MAGIC_NUMBER = 15.0
# for the necessary lowest values of MAGIC_NUMBER look into the numpy docs
class foo(object):
    __array_priority__ = MAGIC_NUMBER
    aarg = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.aarg = 1


    def __rmul__(self,A):
        print(A)
        return 0

    def __mul__(self,A):
        print(A)
        return 0
```

Comment: Note that this will be deprecated in the future. ([source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_priority__)) The correct way to do this will be [Firman' s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43823885/9841338)

Comment: @Alexis Should I delete my answer or write a bold warning in the beginning?

Comment: I'm not sure. Your answer might still be useful to some, so I think the standard way to go is to let upvotes and downvotes operate. :-)